# How would vertical landing scale with size - does bigger = "easier" (actually)?

Tags: landing, blue-origin, vertical-landing

This [Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/09/did-the-fourth-richest-human-just-tease-plans-to-colonize-the-moon/) has two titles that seem to be a bit gratuitous:

> Why Bezos’ rocket is unprecedented — and worth taking seriously
>
> Why Blue Origin’s crazy big rocket might fly, and what it means for spaceflight

and the link itself contains:

> did-the-fourth-richest-human-just-tease-plans-to-colonize-the-moon

The article then links to a [previous article](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/04/astronaut-prime-heres-how-jeff-bezos-plans-to-remake-spaceflight/), with the Bezos quote:

> "The reason I like vertical landing is because it scales so well," he explained. "New Shepard is about 80 feet tall. It’s the shortest vehicle we will ever make. It gets easier to land the vehicles the bigger they get. It’s the inverted pendulum problem. It's easier to balance bigger things. I like those architectures. Parachutes have the opposite problem; as things get bigger, it's very difficult. You can’t build a parachute 1,000 feet in diameter. Even wings, they scale pretty well to a certain size, but they end up being a lot of dead weight to carry."

An example of the [inverted pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) would be balancing a broom stick on your index finger.

Is there a simple way to understand why a substantially larger rocket would be easier to land vertically? All I can think of is that the dry weight would increase faster than size cubed $(L^{>3})$ to maintain structural integrity (the same reason there can't be [Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla) sized exoskeleton creatures) but the drag force would scale only as $(L^{2})$ (keeping aspect ratio constant), but I'm just grasping at straws here. The New Glen first stage will not have the same aspect ratio as the Falcon 9 first stage, as [mentioned in Wired](https://www.wired.com/2016/09/blue-orgins-new-glenn-rocket/):

> But even though, at 270 feet, the New Glenn is much taller than a Falcon 9, the Blue Origin rocket is also much fatter. In terms of aspect ratio, this means it will be easier to control as it comes down.

…but I don't think Bezos' argument is based solely on aspect ratio, and I don't understand why a smaller aspect ratio would make vertical landing easier - is it the larger moment of inertia?

Is this explained or worked out somewhere? If not, is there any physics/engineering rationale that could be expressed here?

[image]

**above:** size comparison of various rockets [from Wired](https://www.wired.com/2016/09/blue-orgins-new-glenn-rocket/) with credit to Blue Origin. Right click to view full size image.

[image]

**above:** illustration of an [inverted-pendulum-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) problem [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Balancer_with_wine_3.JPG).

Comment: A rocket is *not* an inverted pendulum.  There's no fulcrum.

Comment: Is not a gimbaled engine providing about a gee of upward thrust functionally a fulcrum?

Comment: @pericynthion Bezos invoked the term "inverted pendulum", I mentioned the broomstick on the finger example, and the "inverted-pendulum-like" problem. To first order, it doesn't matter if the rocket is accelerating vertically or fixed vertically, the thrust vectoring at the bottom is a good-enough fulcrum to use the term "inverted pendulum" at least metaphorically. However in second order, strong vectoring does decrease vertical thrust, so there will be some coupling.That means your landing is in jeopardy as well and you'd better stop worrying about what is or isn't a fulcrum.

Comment: The difference is that in the inverted pendulum / broomstick-on-finger, the thrust direction is referred to the earth frame. A small angular displacement leads to positive feedback and rapidly diverges if not quickly corrected by the controller/juggler.  On a rocket, the thrust direction is referred to the body frame. Small angular displacements (of body attitude) do not have the same diverging tendency.

Comment: @pericynthion The difference is just semantic - a time derivative. If I have a broom on my finger and it's falling to the right, my brain tells my muscles to *push my finger and the bottom of the broom* to the right with a certain force. The linear and angular inertia of the broom resist this force and torque, and the ratios are the linear and angular accelerations - exactly as in the case of the rocket. The vertical and transverse forces exerted by my finger are analogous to the vertical and transverse forces of the rocket thrust.

Comment: No, there's a fundamental difference, not merely semantic. It's only the feedback mechanism of your brain and vision that allow you to keep the pencil balanced.  As it starts to tilt away, if you do not move your finger (for this thought experiment), the turning moment increases because your finger is pushing up in the earth/LVLH frame and the c.g. of the pencil is moving laterally away from that thrust line. The greater the tilt angle, the greater the moment causing it to turn faster and faster.  ...

Comment: ... On a hovering rocket (again with the active control turned off for this thought experiment) if the thrust line is vertical in the body frame and the rocket tilts by some disturbance, there's no moment to cause it to tilt further.  Even if the thrust axis is misaligned by some angle, then there will be a turning moment but it is constant, not increasing with the body tilt angle.  So now when you turn the active controllers back on in both cases (pencil/pendulum and rocket) you'll see that they have fundamentally different dynamic plants to control.  All else equal, the rocket is easier.

Comment: @pericynthion OK you've got me interested, and that means another day's productivity zeroed out while I dig in and really think about this. Thanks for your persistence!

Comment: Hehe, maybe that issue deserves a question of its own :)

Comment: The experimental way to perform a sanity-check on this reasoning is as follows: try to balance a pencil, inverted pendulum style, on your finger. Now, substitute the pencil for a broomstick. See? It is much easier. Not a proof, just an illustration.

Comment: @xmp125a hmm... I'll have to take your word for it - I can't do either one worth beans. But is it easier fundamentally, or because of the human limitations of experiencing the motion of the pencil - very little tactile feedback, and as far as I can tell, it tips over a lot faster?

Comment: @uhoh The reason is that the time constants of a system are increased by using longer/heavier broomstick, so 1) the dynamic is slower, with speeds that are humanely possible, and 2) the relative effect of air resistance is decreased with 1) as well. Don't know exactly in which relation mass and length are, so I am only commenting, not answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mass of a pendulum doesn't affect its period, but the length does; the longer your rocket, the slower it will tip (in degrees-per-second) while off-balance, and the more time you have to compensate for minor shifts before you have a catastrophe.

Gimbaled rockets have excellent control authority, and the engine thrust will scale with the rocket mass, so in general you can compensate for any small gust of wind or data error if you have sufficient time. A long pendulum gives you that time.

As far as the "fatter" stage, perhaps the advantage there is that the engines, being mounted further out from the centerline, can produce more torque at smaller deflection angles? This would reduce the coupling between vertical acceleration and rotation, affording more tolerance in throttle response time.

Comment: Should we really just be looking at the moment of inertial? That seems to be the right way to include length, width, (aspect ratio), and mass all in a single number.

Comment: I'm a simple unfrozen caveman programmer, and I don't really know precisely what moment of inertia is.

Comment: I don't believe you! :-) However I would believe that you *don't want to remember* precisely what moment of inertia is. This is why I like to ask the questions.

Comment: Nah, seriously I never learned it. I have some idea what it is from context, but can't afford the brainpower to read up right now.